# Understanding "Expression has changed after it was checked" in Angular 2 with Mutable vs Immutable properties

Tags: angular

I've run into the `Expression has changed after it was checked` error in Angular 2.

From what I understand about what the error means and how the change detection mechanism works is that Angular does not like multiple change detection events happening at the same time, and that making changes in `ngOnInit` means that changes have occurred during change detection and that this is a big no-no. What I **don't** understand is why mutating a property in the `ngOnInit` works fine, but creating a new instance of that property results in the error.

Example code:

```
@Component({
    template: `<a-component [input]="list"></a-component>`
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    list = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.list.length = 0;
        this.list.push('x');
    }
}
```

This works. This, does not:

```
@Component({
    template: `<my-component [input]="list"></my-component>`
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    list = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.list = ['x'];
    }
}
```

In this example it appears to me that mutating the property is a better solution because the alternative would involve manually re-triggering change detection.

An explanation of what exactly the change detector is doing here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Angular change detection compares object identity but ignores object content.

In the 1st example you add an item to a list, but the list stays the same - Angular CD is fine with that because it doesn't care about the content of the array (also doesn't recognize changes in arrays at all).

The 2nd example returns a different array instance, which is recognized by Angulars CD and therefore it throws an error.

Comment: I thought that Angular CD would inspect the object content unless the component explicitly used `OnPush` change detection? If the change detector ignores the change in the first example then why is the view updated with the change? P.S thanks for the answer!

Comment: No, if you want to inspect object content, you can use for example the `ngDoCheck()` lifecycle hook and use [differs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?query=differ) to do the change detection yourself. `OnPush` is not what CD checks, but only when Angular runs change detection for a component and it's children and when not.

Comment: I think I understand now. The child component `a-component` renders the content of the list; its change detector therefore picks up changes to the list content because list properties are referenced in its view. The change detector for `MyComponent` however does not look at the list properties because properties of the list are not referenced in its view. If that's correct then does that mean that the change detector for `MyComponent` is never triggered when mutating the list, but is when assigning a new reference? And if so does that mean it's more performant to mutate the list?

Comment: Sounds correct. "renders the content of the list" probably means `*ngFor="..."` which uses `IterableDiffer` to check for changes https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/45cc4441540beba041762c7b0435e839df84e6a4/modules/%40angular/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L142-L147 to do its own change detection.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. Could you answer the last part of the comment as well? I'm not clear on which practice to follow in this case and how each affects performance.

Comment: Do you mean "it's more performant to mutate the list"? Does it matter if it throws an exception? Sure if you do the assignment outside of callbacks called by change detection, it wouldn't throw. I'd expect it to be usually more performant, because it causes less work for change detection and differs would run anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is limitation of debug mode checking implementation. Angular does not create copy of array/object, instead it puts value to map, so when it comes to comparison it checks new value with itself.